# The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module (fsevents)

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, fsevents

I'm trying to create React app using `npx create-react-app first-react-app`.

When it start to create the app, I'm getting the warning below every time. At the end it's create an app. But what is the reason and how can I resolve this problem permanently?

Here is the all logs:

```
yarn add v1.22.10
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.2.1: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.2.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 6 new dependencies.

Installing template dependencies using yarnpkg...
yarn add v1.22.10
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.2.1: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.2.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
warning " > @testing-library/user-event@12.6.0" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=7.21.4".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 17 new dependencies.
Done in 179.26s.
Removing template package using yarnpkg...

yarn remove v1.22.10
[1/2] Removing module cra-template...
[2/2] Regenerating lockfile and installing missing dependencies...
info fsevents@2.2.1: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.2.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
warning " > @testing-library/user-event@12.6.0" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=7.21.4".
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
success Uninstalled packages.
Done in 54.33s.
```

Comment: Given that it's a supported platform warning, the only way to get rid of it would be to use a platform that *is* supported by fsevents, i.e. switch to macOS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. At the moment I have to continue with Windows OS.

Answer (score 17):

You can ignore this warning. See more about this warning [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/3462#issuecomment-353706532)

> this is expected and can be ignored. We can't yet ignore optional packages (in this case canvas)

To disable this message try using:

```
yarn config set ignore-engines true
```

Or try use `--use-npm --no-optional` flags

```
npx create-react-app first-react-app --use-npm --no-optional
```

Comment: Thanks for information and your suggestion, but still getting warnings.

Comment: @Sinan.D, I updated the answer, try `--use-npm` flag

Comment: @Sinan.D, try `npx create-react-app first-react-app --use-npm --no-optional`. If it helps, let me know, I'll update the answer

Comment: Thanks again, get the warnings again but at hte end it's creating. Maybe the only way to get rid of it would be to use a platform that is supported by fsevents, i.e. switch to macOS as @jonrsharpe suggested.

Comment: @Sinan.D, yes, this will be the best solution)

Answer (score 8):

I tried all the solutions offered here, but the best solution was to add both

```
--ignore-engines --ignore-platform
```

I'm a Windows 10 user, my yarn version is 1.22.17. Probably it will work also for npm. My problem came from fsevents@2.3.2

So the final cmdlet was:

```
yarn install --ignore-engines --ignore-platform
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Issue still remains

`$ yarn global --ignore-engines --ignore-platform add  n                                                                                                                                    
yarn global v1.22.17
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error n@8.0.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global for documentation about this command.`